# Add new tab on tabPanel extJS

Tags: extjs

I'm just starting to learn extJS, so don't be very strict for my questions).
So this is my Main.js:

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Main', {
  extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
  xtype: 'app-main',

  requires: [
    'Ext.plugin.Viewport',
    'Ext.window.MessageBox',

    'MyApp.view.main.MainController',
    'MyApp.view.main.MainModel',
    'MyApp.view.main.List',
  ],

  controller: 'main',
  viewModel: 'main',
  plugins: 'viewport',

  ui: 'navigation',

  header: {
    layout: {
      align: 'stretchmax',
    },
    title: {
      bind: {
        text: 'Some items',
      },
      flex: 0,
    },
    items: [
      {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Items',
        margin: '10',
        handler: 'onMouseDown', // this is my handler for create new tab
      },
      {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Logout',
        margin: '10',
        handler: 'onClickButton',
      },
    ],
  },

  tabBar: {
    flex: 1,
    layout: {
      align: 'stretch',
      overflowHandler: 'none',
    },
  },

  defaults: {
    bodyPadding: 20,
    tabConfig: {
      responsiveConfig: {
        wide: {
          iconAlign: 'left',
          textAlign: 'left',
        },
        tall: {
          iconAlign: 'top',
          textAlign: 'center',
          width: 120,
        },
      },
    },
  },

  items: [
    {
      title: 'Items',
      items: [
        {
          xtype: 'mainlist',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

And this is my MainController.js:

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MainController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

  alias: 'controller.main',

  onConfirm: function (choice) {
    if (choice === 'yes') {
      //
    }
  },

  onClickButton: function () {
    localStorage.removeItem('MyAppLoggedIn');

    this.getView().destroy();

    Ext.create({
      xtype: 'login',
    });
  },

  onMouseDown: function () {
    var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
      listeners: {
        tabchange: function (newTab) {
          if (newTab) {
            onAddTab(tabPanel);
          }
        },
      },
      items: [
        {
          title: 'Items',
          items: [
            {
              xtype: 'mainlist',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(), // I want to render to tabPanel, not to body
    });
  },
});
```

After click I need to create a new Tab in my tabPanel.
May be I need just to change renderTo, but T'm sure that an elegant way exists:

renderTo: Ext.select('some tab class')

Answer (score 0):

To add `Tab` to this `Tab.Panel` you need to use `add` function on the view.
To get `View` in `ViewController` you can use [`this.getView()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.app.ViewController.html#method-getView) function.

Example on Sencha (dynamically add tabs): https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#reorderable-tabs

Example Your ViewController:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MainController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

  alias: 'controller.main',

  onConfirm: function (choice) {
    if (choice === 'yes') {
      //
    }
  },

  onClickButton: function () {
    localStorage.removeItem('MyAppLoggedIn');

    this.getView().destroy();

    Ext.create({
      xtype: 'login',
    });
  },

  onMouseDown: function () {
    var tabPanel = this.getView();

    tabPanel.add({
        
        items: [{
           html: "xyz"
        }]
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: norbeq, thanks for your answer, but it still not adding tabs... May be I need to change smth in Main.js

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? Have you check that is `onMouseDown` function  triggered?

Comment: There are no errors at all. And yes - I have already check onMouseDown function triggering. I think that problem can be in the structure. But - I assigned 'id' in ViewController for items,  tried to use Ext.getCmp('id') and add tab - tab inserted, but not in tabPanel

Comment: So you refer to bad panel